# A pdf reader that can display 3 pages in a row

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-viewer

My pdf reader (evince) supports dual display, i.e pages are not shown consecutively but 2 in a row:

`slide 1 | slide 2`
`slide 3 | slide 4`

Use case: I'm viewing a PDF with a slide on each page and the best fit would be to watch 3x2 pages (slides) at once.

`slide 1 | slide 2 | slide 3`
`slide 4 | slide 5 | slide 6`

Is there a reader, preferably for linux, that supports this?

Long story short:
yes there is: qpdfview
for windows @Timmy recommends Foxit
depending on your nerves printing and rotating your screen is an option, thanks again to @Timmy for his efforts.

### Progress:

@Timmy suggests printing to file with 6 original pages per new page.

I link to [this](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~frank/ENG/beamer/example/Beamer-class-example2.pdf) as a sample document since it's the first google result for 'latex beamer example'. In case the link dies, any slide with ratio 4:3 will do.

With evince, I tried:

[image]
[image]
[image]

result:
[image]

The slides overlap and there's plenty of empty space(select image to see better)

Comment: 3x2 pages > On which monitor would each of those six pages be displayed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt all 6 pages are to be displayed on the same monitor!

Comment: I don't think there is a viewer with that functionality. So would it be convenient to use a virtual printer to "print" your document into another pdf file that has 6 pages per "sheet"? It's rather common for presentation handouts, but you'd be printing to pdf instead of paper.

Comment: @Timmy This is a good idea! I just tried it but I don't get it to work: With Evince, I get overlapping slides and a huge margin between the rows. Can anyone report an application and exact printing parameters for this task?

Comment: You just need to choose a suitable paper type depending on the dimensions of your slides and increase the scale to crop out the margins. Try selecting a size with longer length and smaller width since you are printing from 1x1 to 3x2 slides per page. It would help if you could post a link to a sample document so we could test it

Comment: very suitable for this [super ultra-wide screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jSxvjT6Ec0) ;)

Comment: Moreso, in qpdfview settings you can increase the number of pages in a row above 3 pages. I just tested 6 in a row. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**qpdfview** offers "multipage"-view, which does display 3 pages in a row. Note that `view` → `continuous` needs to be selected as well for comfortable viewing.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an editor with such a viewing option, but there may be workarounds through the PDF printer.

After going through the page sizes in the print options on [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), there were a couple that didn't produce overlap, namely **c** and **e**. Also make sure to uncheck both options under **Page Handling** and select **Fit to Printable Area** for the page scaling.

The resulting documents has 6 slides that do not overlap. They do, however, have large spaces between the rows due to the fact that (4x3) * (3x2) = 12x6 = 1x2, which is not a common ratio you'd find on normal papers, and printing on an envelope paper resulted in very small pages. Also, because Evince does not have an "Auto Center" option. [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) had the same issue as well.

[image]

I would recommend rotating your screen 90 degrees <s>and printing them in a vertical orientation instead, since it highly reduces the white space, even on a regular A4 paper</s> (**Edit**) and using dual view to display 6 slides in a 2x3 view

[image]

<sup>Click each image to enlarge</sup>

---

Edit: I tried the printing it with [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) on Windows and there was no extra white space between the rows.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get the linux setup to work:

Comment: space between rows is unacceptable since I'm already able to view 2x2 via 'dual'-option. So seeing only 3 full slides and 3 headers would be a step back. Rotating and viewing 2x3 is a good hack, this way no printing is needed due to dual-option. A way to print it close-fitting 3x2 would be nice though...

Comment: @user2740 A 3x2 close-fit printing works with Foxit Reader, but I could only test it on Windows. I also updated the answer with your dual-view rotated screen idea

Comment: @user2740 but even with that, you'd still get a larger slide view with a rotated screen, unless you have one of those [*really* wide monitors](http://assets.hardwaresphere.com/uploads/2009/06/nec-crv43-43-inch-curved-lcd-monitor.jpg) :)